# How to get the address of the return value of a function in C++

Tags: c++

Given this prototype which does a Endian conversion:

```
time_t Flip( time_t );
```

I would like to use the return value in a function that takes a BYTE* as an argument.
Something like this:

```
SetBytesAt( 0, (BYTE*)&(Flip( t )) );
```

But this does not compile.  Gives me this error "& requires l-value".
If the () are removed from around the Flip function, the same error is generated.

Now, I know that I can just do this:

```
time_t temp_t = Flip( t );
SetBytesAt( 0, (BYTE*)&temp_t );
```

But it seems to me that I should be able to accomplish the same thing without the temporary temp_t variable.

Comment: On many (most?) architectures the value returned from a function will be in a register, so until/unless it's assigned to a variable, it won't have an address at all.

Comment: What does `SetBytesAt` do, anyway? Would be kind of useful to know to answer this properly...

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, no.  You cannot take the address of a temporary (more correctly, an [r-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29)).  That's just the way the language has been defined.

Comment: -1 "Temporaries (more correctly, r-values) don't have addresses." is incorrect. Some of them are not guaranteed to have addresses. Others are guaranteed to have addresses if they're used in any way that requires an address. In particular, you can call methods on temporaries (rvalues) of class type.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You are correct, clearly!  I've simplified my wording accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try this at home.

```
template <typename T>
class AddressableTemporary
{
public:

    AddressableTemporary(T const value)
        : value_(value)
    {
    }

    operator T*() { return &value_; }

private:

    T value_;
};

template <typename T>
AddressableTemporary<T> MakeAddressable(T value)
{
    return AddressableTemporary<T>(value);
}
```

Used as:

```
int  F() { return 42; }
void G(int const* const p) { std::cout << *p; }

int main()
{
    G(MakeAddressable(F()));
}
```

But really, don't do this.  Either use a variable, or write a wrapper function that encapsulates usage of the variable, or rework your code so that you don't need to worry about this (e.g., modify the function so that it takes, say, a const reference).

Comment: And... now my head hurts.  :)

Comment: And you had to make the conversion implicit?

Comment: Nice answer :) The power of templates demonstrated once again.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  Well, I suppose the converting constructor could be explicit.  And it would benefit from some rvalue reference love.  I did say not to do this at all, though. :-)

Comment: What would be wrong with: `template<typename T> T const * get_address(T const &t) { return &t; }` (other than that `SetBytesAt` would have to accept pointer-to-const).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a temporary variable. You can only take address of l-values. There is no way to take address of a return value.

On some platforms, return value is only stored in a register and hence doesn't even have an address. You need to store it in memory before you can pass its address to another function.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, that is not possible in C++.

Ask yourself this: how will you access the modified result after `SetBytesAt` returns?

Return values are normally copied (or moved) to an actual variable in the caller function. The temporary space reserved for the returned value is no longer available after the function returns. Theoretically, you would be stack memory that is no longer valid. This mistake happens in practice when returning references to local variables.

Comment: It's the other way round.  The space for the return value can get clobbered *because* the standard prohibits its address being taken.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it became possible in C++11. There, r-value references were introduced. However, I don't know, which compiler does it already.

Comment: Rvalue references do not magically enable taking the address of an rvalue.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: why "magically"? Of course, there is an different syntax, the example wouldn't go as it is. However, the case the OP construct is more or less exactly the reason why r-value references where introduced.

Comment: This is the top comment. It's been 8 years since this response and I hadn't even considered this could be possible until I saw a little ``&`` right before a function call, and it was all passed as a param too. This while reading through some microsoft code. Sadly OP seems to be an account gone inactive after this question. Props.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, for the exact reason given by the error message - `& requires l-value`.

The call `Flip(t)` is not an l-value, so it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It's no big deal to do what you want, but it's unclean.

Here goes:

```
template< class Type >
Type const& ref( Type const& v ) { return v; }

int main()
{
    time_t t = blah blah;
    SetBytesAt( 0, const_cast<Byte*>( reinterpret_cast<Byte const*>( &ref( Flip( t ) ) ) ) );
}
```

Technically this can work if `SetBytesAt` copies the bytes, but if `SetBytesAt` stores the pointer, and that pointer is later used, then it's undefined behavior.

Anyway, don't do that.

Now I'll list what's wrong with the original concept:

- Discarding type knowledge by using typeless pointer argument.
  → Means a lot of extra work because the type is not known.
- Discarding const knowledge by using pointer to non-const argument.
  → Means a lot of extra work because the constness is not known.
- Flipping byte order of data = ungood except in low level network code.
  → Means a lot of extra work because the byte order is not known.

So, again, don't do that.

Instead, do the opposite: preserve type information, preserve constness information, and don't mess with the raw bytes.